# Problema con dos sentencias preparadas en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Buen día comunidad, primero que nada agradecer la ayuda, estoy en proceso de aprendizaje y con este problema no doy la solución quizás sea algo básico pero me supero. Gracias por su ayuda.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una sentencia preparada que me trae un array de una base de datos mysql

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT `Titulo`, `Descripcion`, `Ciudad`, `imgAyuda` FROM `registro_diario_archivos`");                      
        $sentencia->execute();
        $sentencia->bind_result($titulo, $descrip, $ciudad, $imgAyuda); 
        $data = array();
        while ($sentencia->fetch()) {  
            
        $imgAyuda = ($imgAyuda == 0)?'defaultImg.jpg':$diario->ConsultImgHelp($imgAyuda, $con); 

        $data [] = array(                
            "titulo"        => $titulo,
            "descrip"       => $descrip,
            "ciudad"        => $ciudad,
            "img_ayuda"     => $imgAyuda
            
        );
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        $sentencia->close();
        $con->close();
```

La consulta funciona perfecto, pero el problema me surge cuando coloco la función que tengo donde debo enviar el id de la img ConsultImgHelp($imgAyuda, $con) aquí se daña y me genera esta error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Formulario\Funciones\funcionesDiario.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Formulario\diario\diarioAppEjecutable.php(132): FuncionesDiario->ConsultImgHelp(7, Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Formulario\Funciones\funcionesDiario.php on line 20
```

la función que llama es esta

```
 function ConsultImgHelp($idImg, $con){   

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `NombreImg` FROM `img_help_viajero` WHERE `ID_Img` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $idImg);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($nombre);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

return $nombre;
```

}

Por separado funciona perfectamente el problema es cuando introduzco la función ConsultImgHelp($idImg, $con) dentro del while. Igualmente funciona si hago la primera consulta sin sentencia preparada.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El problema es que falla la consulta para obtener nombre de imagen. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar la estructura de las dos tablas. Solo así podemos tratar de averiguar cuál es el problema. Además, puedes ahorrarte esa segunda consulta usando [JOINs](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer en este bloque es una pésima idea:

```
    while ($sentencia->fetch()) {              
        $imgAyuda = ($imgAyuda == 0)?'defaultImg.jpg':$diario->ConsultImgHelp($imgAyuda, $con); 
        // ...
```

¿Por qué? Porque **estarías ejecutando tantas consultas como filas tenga el primer resultado**, cuando puedes obtener todo de una vez en el primer conjunto de resultados si unes ambas tablas mediante `JOIN`. Para determinar el valor que debe tener la columna del nombre de la imagen puedes usar `CASE`.

Otra ventaja de hacer esto es que aprovecharías los supuestos índices que tendrían las tablas (si es que has diseñado bien tu modelo de datos), ganando mucho más en rendimiento.

Veamos:

```
$sql="SELECT 
          r.`Titulo`, 
          r.`Descripcion`, 
          r.`Ciudad`,
          (CASE r.`imgAyuda` WHEN 0 THEN 'defaultImg.jpg' ELSE i.`NombreImg` END) 
    FROM `registro_diario_archivos` AS r 
    LEFT JOIN `img_help_viajero` AS i ON r.`imgAyuda`=i.`ID_Img`";

$sentencia = $con->prepare($sql);                      
        $sentencia->execute();
        $sentencia->bind_result($titulo, $descrip, $ciudad, $imgAyuda); 
        $data = array();
        while ($sentencia->fetch()) {              
            $data [] = array(                
                "titulo"        => $titulo,
                "descrip"       => $descrip,
                "ciudad"        => $ciudad,
                "img_ayuda"     => $imgAyuda            
            );
        }
        $sentencia->close();
        $con->close();  
        echo json_encode($data);
```

### Post-Data

Si en la tabla `img_help_viajero` tú tuvieras una fila con `ID_Img` igual a `0` y con `NombreImg`  igual a `defaultImg.jpg` ni siquiera sería necesario el `CASE`, porque la consulta tomaría de forma natural el valor asociado.